# Failed to launch gwt: BeanDefinitionStoreException

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, gwt

When trying to run gwt build and run gwt from terminal. GWT application gets launched. When I'm trying to launch default browser in development mode, I'm getting the following error
`HTTP ERROR: 503

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
RequestURI=/OneApp.jsp`

When I tried to look into jetty tab, The following error log was shown:

`00:36:45.318 [ERROR] 503 - GET /OneApp.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 (127.0.0.1) 1317 bytes
00:00:00.002 [WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@1e20ad5{/,/home/sainathreddy/projects/branches/BOAAdjustment/app/widget/oneapp/target/ROOT}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'searchServicePublic' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/sainathreddy/projects/branches/BOAAdjustment/app/widget/oneapp/target/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/search.client-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'url.service.composite.search' in string value "${url.service.composite.search}/public"    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)     at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:174)    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)`

I'm unable to launch gwt from terminal. I have used the following commands

```
mvn clean install gwt:run
```

Comment: Look at the logs **Invalid bean definition with name 'searchServicePublic'**

Comment: This one also **Could not resolve placeholder 'url.service.composite.search' in string value**

Comment: searchServicePublic path was commented out in config file.